# R - How to conditionally color the values of a data.frame and make a plot

Tags: r, colors, dataframe, performanceanalytics

I have this dataframe created with the function table.CalendarReturns from the PerfomanceAnalytics package (the rownames are the years and the colnames are the months ):

```
tabRet

> 
 gen  feb  mar  apr  may  jun  jul  aug sep  oct nov  dec System
 2004 0.0  3.5  2.9  2.0  1.1 -0.4  1.2 3.3  0.9 1.8  3.0 -0.6   20.1
 2005 1.6  2.3 -1.2  4.0  0.0  1.6 -1.4 2.4  0.7 2.9  2.9  0.4   17.3
 2006 0.8  2.7  0.3  1.4  6.2 -2.6  2.1 2.8  0.5 0.3  0.7  3.1   19.6
 2007 1.3  0.1  1.4  0.1  1.6 -1.0  1.0 1.5 -0.7 1.0  1.3 -0.7    7.0
 2008 1.4 -1.2  2.2  1.2 -0.3 -0.8  2.2 0.4  1.1 0.1  4.4 -1.3    9.7
 2009 4.8  3.2  1.6  3.5  0.7  1.7  2.1 2.2  2.5 1.9  1.5  2.8   32.4
 2010 3.5  0.5  0.4  1.3  1.8  3.8  3.7 3.0  1.1 1.2  3.9  3.4   31.2    
 2011 4.3  2.1  1.6 -0.8  3.9  1.5  4.0 5.4  2.3 2.9  0.2  1.5   33.0
 2012 1.1  1.9 -0.1  2.3  1.0  3.6  1.5 0.7  0.0 1.5  1.2  0.5   16.3
 2013 0.8  2.5  1.2  1.4  0.0  1.7  2.3 1.7  0.5 0.2  1.3  0.6   15.1
 2014 0.1  0.7  0.3 -0.7  1.0  1.0  0.2 0.9 -0.7 2.3  1.4  1.4    8.2
 2015 2.3  1.0  1.1  3.1  4.5 -0.7 -0.3 2.3  2.4 0.4 -1.3  1.0   16.7
 2016 2.1  2.5  0.9  1.0  0.2   NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA   NA    7.0
```

I would like to create a plot with something like this for the colors of the numbers: `ifelse(values< 0,'red','black')`.

I tried with the addtable2plot function, from the plotrix package with bad results.
Any tips about this problem? Thank you in advance guys.

EDIT:
I need something like this but with the negative numbers in red:

```
textplot(Hmisc::format.df(tabRet, na.blank=TRUE, numeric.dollar=FALSE, cdec=rep(1,dim(tabRet)[2])), rmar = 0.8, cmar = 1, max.cex=.9, halign = "center", valign = "center", row.valign="center", wrap.rownames=20, wrap.colnames=10, col.colnames="Darkblue",col.rownames="Darkblue", mar = c(0,0,4,0)+0.1) title(main="Calendar Monthly Returns",col.main="Darkblue", cex.main=1)
```

[PLOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duRfy.jpg)

Comment: Use ggplot ( library: `ggplot2`). You can create a variable `c<-ifelse(values< 0,'a','b')` and then use that variable in `color=` within ggplot.  See this for further understanding : http://zevross.com/blog/2014/08/04/beautiful-plotting-in-r-a-ggplot2-cheatsheet-3/

Comment: Though if you use `ggplot` you'll certainly need to reshape your months into long format, see `tidyr::gather` or `reshape2::melt`.

Comment: does this allow me to plot this table in that form? Because for plotting that table I tried:

 textplot(Hmisc::format.df(tabRet, na.blank=TRUE, numeric.dollar=FALSE,                          cdec=rep(1,dim(tabRet)[2])), rmar = 0.8, cmar = 1,  max.cex=.9,         halign = "center", valign = "center", row.valign="center", wrap.rownames=20,
         wrap.colnames=10, col.colnames="Darkblue",col.rownames="Darkblue", mar = c(0,0,4,0)+0.1)
title(main="Calendar Monthly Returns",col.main="Darkblue", cex.main=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `col.data=ifelse(tabRet<0,'red','black'),` after `col.rownames="Darkblue",` to your code

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `geom_tile{ggplot2}` with a reproducible example:

```
# load libraries
  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggthemes)
  library(data.table)
  library(PerformanceAnalytics)

# load data
  data(managers)
  df <- as.data.frame(t(table.CalendarReturns(managers[,c(1,7,8)])))

#  Convert row names into first column
  df <- setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
  setnames(df, "rn", "month")

# reshape your data
   df2 <- melt(df, id.var = "month")

# Plot
ggplot(df2, aes(x=month, y=variable)) + 
      geom_tile( fill= "white", color = "white") +
      geom_text(aes(label=value, color= value < 0)) +
      scale_color_manual(guide=FALSE, values=c("red", "black")) +
      theme_pander( ) +
      theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold")) +
      ggtitle("Calendar Monthly Returns")
```

[image]

You can also choose to fill the tiles instead of the text.

```
ggplot(df2) +
  geom_tile( aes(x=month , y=variable, fill= value < 0), color = "gray70", alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual(guide=FALSE, values=c("red", "black")) +
  theme_pander()
```

[image]

In any case, this answer provides a general approach to conditional colors in `ggplot`.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point( aes(color= ifelse(mpg > 20, "A", "B")) )  +
  scale_color_manual(guide=FALSE, values=c("red", "black"))
```

[image]

You can also do this using `base`:

```
plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, 
     col=ifelse( mtcars$mpg > 20 ,"red", "black") )
```

Comment: Not exactly, I edited my original answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are looking for:

```
require(tidyr)
require(ggplot2)
d<-data.table(gen=seq(2004,2016,1),Jan=round(rnorm(13)),Feb=round(rnorm(13)),Mar=round(rnorm(13)))
gd<-gather(d,key=gen)
gd$col<-ifelse(gd$value<0.5,"1","0")
ggplot(data=gd,aes(x=gen,y=value,color=col))+geom_tile(aes(fill=col))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly, I edited my original answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I found the solution, I hope this code will serve you this code receives a data.frame and converts it into conditional format, the value of the cells is shown in the columns

[Data i  a data.frame][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jETa8.png

```
pmensual <- readXL("D:precipitacion mensual 
2021/Base de Datos Precipitación mensual .xls",
                   rownames=FALSE, header=TRUE, na="", sheet="Preci_mes", 
                   stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

nba.m <- melt(pmensual)
nba.s <- ddply(nba.m, .(variable), transform)
ggplot(nba.s, aes(variable, Nombre)) + 
   geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white") +
   #scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c("blue", "green", "red"))+
   scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "red", mid = "blue", midpoint = 400) +
   geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1)), size= 3.5, vjust = 0.4)+
   scale_x_discrete("Mes", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
   scale_y_discrete("Estaciones", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
   theme( legend.position="bottom", legend.title=element_text(), panel.background = 
   element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "gray"),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray"))+
   
   labs(title = "Mapa de Calor Precipitaciones en la zona de Estudio",
        subtitle = "Precipitacion Acumulada al mes" , fill = "Precipitacion mm" )
```

[result ][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVYV4.png